# How to handle functions of a multi-parameter typeclass, who not need every type of the typeclass?

Tags: haskell

I've defined a typeclass similar to an interface with a bunch of functions required for my program. Sadly, it needs multiple polymorphic types, but not every function of this multi-parameter typeclass needs every type. GHC haunts me with undeduceable types and i can't get the code running.

A reduced example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

class Foo a b where
    -- ...
    bar :: a -> ()

baz :: Foo a b => a -> ()
baz = bar
```

GHC says

```
Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
```

How can I do this for `b`? Especially when I want to keep `b` polymorphic. Only an instance of `Foo` should define what this type is.

Comment: Refactor your typeclasses to avoid functions that do not depend on the entirety of the context. Multiparameter typeclasses are rather awkward anyway - if you can avoid them, do.

Answer (score 13):

This is impossible.

The underlying problem is that a multiparameter type class depends on *every* type parameter. If a particular definition in the class doesn't use every type parameter, the compiler will never be able to know what instance you mean, and you'll never even be able to specify it.  Consider the following example:

```
class Foo a b where
    bar :: String -> IO a

instance Foo Int Char where
    bar x = return $ read x

instance Foo Int () where
    bar x = read <$> readFile x
```

Those two instances do entirely different things with their parameter. The only way the compiler has to select one of those instances is matching both type parameters. But there's no way to specify what the type parameter *is*. The class is just plain broken. There's no way to ever call the `bar` function, because you can never provide enough information for the compiler to resolve the class instance to use.

So why is the class definition not rejected by the compiler? Because you can sometimes make it work, with the `FunctionalDependencies` extension.

If a class has multiple parameters, but they're related, that information can sometimes be added to the definition of the class in a way that allows a class member to not use every type variable in the class's definition.

```
class Foo a b | a -> b where
    bar :: String -> IO a
```

With that definition (which requires the `FunctionalDependencies` extension), you are telling the compiler that for any particular choice of `a`, there is only one valid choice of `b`. Attempting to even define both of the above instances would be a compile error.

Given that, the compiler knows that it can select the instance of `Foo` to use based only on the type `a`. In that case, `bar` can be called.

Comment: Does that mean that if i want a similar functionality, i need to put those function into smaller suitable typeclasses and then let the upper typeclass depend on it?

Comment: If you attempt to combine them all into one superclass, you'll end up with the same problem. Honestly, it sounds like you're overusing classes. It's possible you're not, but it's at least equally possible that there's a simpler approach.

Comment: Hm i don't know. Often i use typeclasses to abstract IO away, so that it can depend on another layer before IO. Shouldn't i do that?

Comment: @Vektorweg: what's wrong with `Control.Monad.IO.Class` and `liftIO` for that purpose?  Possibly augmented with `monad-control` or `exceptions` if you're using exceptions).

Answer (score 3):

Splitting it in smaller typeclasses might be sufficient.

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

class Fo a => Foo a b where
    -- ...
    foo :: a -> b -> ()


class Fo a where
    bar :: a -> ()


baz :: Foo a b => a -> ()
baz = bar
```

Comment: This will only possibly work if you define something like `instance Foo Int b`, in which case the compiler will be able to select an instance based solely on the first parameter.  And if that's the case, you can simply use `Fo` instead of `Foo` because all your instances would be identical anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you really want to use more than one instance for a given `a` (and so cannot use functional dependencies as others mentioned), one possibility which may or may not be right for you is to use a newtype *tagged* with a "phantom" type used only to guide type selection.  This compiles:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

newtype Tagged t a = Tagged { unTagged :: a }   -- Also defined in the tagged package
                                                -- on Hackage

class Foo a b where
    bar :: Tagged b a -> ()

baz :: Foo a b => Tagged b a -> ()
baz = bar
```

Then you will be able to wrap your values in such a way that you can give an explicit type annotation to select the right instance.

Answer (score 2):

Another way of refactoring multi-parameter type classes when they get awkward is to use the [TypeFamilies](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/Type_families) extension. Like [FunctionalDependencies](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Functional_dependencies), this works well when you can reframe your class as having only a single parameter (or at least, fewer parameter), with the other types that are different from instance to instance being *computed from* the actual class parameters.

Generally I've found whenever I thought I needed a multi-parameter type class, the parameters almost always varied *together* rather than varying independently. In this situation it's much easier to pick one as "primary" and use some system for determining the others from it. Functional dependencies can do this as well as type families, but many find type families a lot easier to understand.

Here's an example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, FlexibleInstances #-}

class Glue a where 
    type Glued a
    glue :: a -> a -> Glued a


instance Glue Char where 
    type Glued Char = String
    glue x y = [x, y]


instance Glue String where 
    type Glued String = String
    glue x y = x ++ y


glueBothWays :: Glue a => a -> a -> (Glued a, Glued a)
glueBothWays x y = (glue x y, glue y x)
```

The above declares a class `Glue` of types that can be glued together with the `glue` operation, and that have a corresponding type which is the result of the "gluing".

I then declared a couple of instances; `Glued Char` is `String`, `Glued String` is also just `String`.

Finally I wrote a function to show how you use `Glued` when you're being polymorphic over the instance of `Glue` you're using; basically you "call" `Glued` as a function in your type signatures; this means `glueBothWays` doesn't "know" what type `Glued a` is, but it knows how it corresponds to `a`. You can even use `Glued Char` as a type, if you know you're gluing Chars but don't want to hard-code the assumption that `Glued Char = String`.